# How to save your bitcoins to avoid gambling

Tags: bitcoind

I am a bit addicted to gambling.
Whenever I receive any amount in my blockchain wallet, I play on it and always lost it.

Suggest some ways to save and avoid gambling.

Comment: Please highlight how this question is specific to Bitcoin. I tend towards closing this as offtopic, as self-management and behaviour are not in the focus of this site.

Comment: Perhaps if you reworded your question along the lines of "How can I receive bitcoin, but be prevented from immediately spending it?" you may get some more generally useful multisig or nLockTime related answers.

Comment: Get help. You have a gambling problem. There are a number of resources, I suggest https://www.problemgambling.ca/EN/GettingHelp/Pages/SelfHelpWorkbook.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put your BTC in a paper wallet, which makes them less accessible, especially if you store that paper wallet in a bank deposit box or another offsite, secure location. However, this is not really a technical problem. You should seek out a support group for gambling addiction if you cannot control yourself.